# How to get two words from one column in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a column called `process` in my table called `orders`. I am trying to display `process` that have `waiting` and `processing`.

I have tried `SELECT process FROM orders WHERE process='waiting' AND process='processing'`

and

`SELECT process FROM orders WHERE process='waiting', process='processing'`

However, it's not working. How can I do this?

```
Example:

orderid process 
   1    waiting
   2    
   3
```

Then the process changes of the orderid 1 to `processing` from `waiting`

The results would still display that order but with `processing`.

Right now, when the order changes from `waiting` it dissappears. I'd like to be able to see it `processing` also

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A field can not have two different values in a row. You should use OR instead of AND or use following query:

```
SELECT process FROM orders WHERE process IN ('waiting', 'process');
```